# Transform dataframe by repeating rows and create a variable counting values of two variables

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, rows, replicate

This is a little subset of the data :

I have :

```
df 

ID numberPOS numberNEG
 1         2         3
 2         5         4
 3         1         2
```

and my wish is to transform dataframe with a new variable `statut` counting the number of times negative and positive and repeat rows for each `ID` like this :

```
df
ID numberPOS numberNEG statut
1          2         3    POS
1          2         3    POS
1          2         3    NEG
1          2         3    NEG
1          2         3    NEG
2          5         4    POS
2          5         4    POS
2          5         4    POS
2          5         4    POS
2          5         4    POS
2          5         4    NEG
2          5         4    NEG
2          5         4    NEG
2          5         4    NEG
3          1         2    POS
3          1         2    NEG
3          1         2    NEG
```

So the first row is repeated 5 times because numberPOS + numberNEG = 2 + 3 = 5.
And i would like to create the variable statut for each row 2 times POS and 3 times NEG.
Anyone see the issue?
Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the `base` package, a solution could be this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3),numberPOS=c(2,5,1),numberNEG=c(3,4,2))

do.call("rbind",lapply(df$ID, function(id) {
  fittingRowIndex <- df$ID==id
  fittingRow <- df[fittingRowIndex,]
  newDf <- fittingRow[rep(1,fittingRow$numberPOS+fittingRow$numberNEG),]
  newDf$statut <- rep(c("POS","NEG"),times=c(fittingRow$numberPOS,fittingRow$numberNEG))
  newDf
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unnest` after creating the 'statut' based on the values in 'numberPOS', 'numberNEG'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(statut = map2(numberPOS, numberNEG,
         ~ rep(c('POS', 'NEG'), c(.x, .y)))) %>% 
    unnest(c(statut))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 x 4
#      ID numberPOS numberNEG statut
#   <int>     <int>     <int> <chr> 
# 1     1         2         3 POS   
# 2     1         2         3 POS   
# 3     1         2         3 NEG   
# 4     1         2         3 NEG   
# 5     1         2         3 NEG   
# 6     2         5         4 POS   
# 7     2         5         4 POS   
# 8     2         5         4 POS   
# 9     2         5         4 POS   
#10     2         5         4 POS   
#11     2         5         4 NEG   
#12     2         5         4 NEG   
#13     2         5         4 NEG   
#14     2         5         4 NEG   
#15     3         1         2 POS   
#16     3         1         2 NEG   
#17     3         1         2 NEG
```

---

Or another option with `uncount` and `rep`

```
df %>%
   uncount(numberPOS + numberNEG) %>% 
   mutate(statut = rep(rep(c("POS", "NEG"), nrow(df)), c(t(df[-1]))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, numberPOS = c(2L, 5L, 1L), numberNEG = c(3L, 
4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```